# Email alerts when RAID fails on IBM server?

Tags: raid, windows-server-2008-r2, ibm-xseries, ibm

Have two RAID controllers on an IBM server (X3500 M3) running Windows 2008R2:

- ServeRAID M5014SAS/SATA Controller
- LSI Adapter, SAS 3000 series, 4-port with 1064E

Can anyone explain how to get email alerts when a disk fails on either of these 2 IBM-provided controllers?

Can this be setup from within Windows 2008R2?  I guess we would need to download appropriate monitoring software from IBM to do this ... but I can't find the right software to download.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install the IBM ServeRAID software; pretty certain there should be an option for email alerts in there. A step better is to do that, and also set up an IBM Director server for your environment, if you've got more than a handful of servers.

Comment: Thanks much mfinni!  Found the software at the IBM ServeRAID Software Matrix, at http://www-947.ibm.com/support/entry/portal/docdisplay?brand=5000008&lndocid=SERV-RAID  In the tools menu of that software, there is an option to setup all kinds of alerts, including email alerts.

Comment: BTW, the exact software we downloaded was the MSM, or MegaRAID Storage Manager, which is actually made by LSI.  It recognizes both of our controllers.

Answer (score 2):

There are three "vendor" methods to get alerts from the hardware:

- Configure the IMM to send alerts/SNMP traps on events (noweight option)
- Use ServeRAID manager to configure alerts (lightweight option)
- Setup Director and configure alerts in Director (very heavyweight option)

As mfinni said, if you have a large IBM environment you'll benefit the most from Director. If you only have a few servers, the IMM option is the best way of getting hardware alerts as it gives you not just RAID events, but also memory, processor, etc. errors.

Comment: Especially like that you've noted how light/heavy the load is for each option.  We just have 1 IBM server at this particular location, so we'll be sticking with the ServeRAID manager software for now.  For the Integrated Management Module (IMM) config, we'll keep that in mind for the future.

Comment: I'd really suggest configuring the IMM now - there's no downside to doing so and it can provide you valuable information about the entire hardware package.